# Banshee CPU usage > 100%

Tags: banshee, cpu

Banshee CPU usage peaks and maintains >= 100% (according to `htop`) when I do simple,  nontrivial things.  Even deleting files via Banshee results in >= 100% CPU usage.

I have tried several sugggestions from other AskUbuntu questions such as
[disable BPM](https://askubuntu.com/a/43920/156588) and [other extensions](https://askubuntu.com/a/30675/156588).

Really, all I do is delete one song via Banshee, and it takes up >= 100% CPU usage and never stops.

Comment: Have you tried purging it `sudo apt-get purge banshee` , clean `sudo apt-get autoremove` , then install it again without optional packages  `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install bamshee`

Answer (score 1):

It is answered in [top command on ubuntu multicore cpu shows cpu usage >100%](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707203/top-command-on-ubuntu-multicore-cpu-shows-cpu-usage-100)

By default, top displays CPU usage as a percentage of a single CPU. On multi-core systems, you can see percentages of CPU usage are greater than 100%. You can toggle this behavior by hitting Shift + i while top is running to show the overall percentage of available CPUs in use.

htop is a better alternative of top. In htop, you can see how your programs consuming all of the 32 cores.